# Completion block for graphics animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

My problem is that I've 2 graphics animation one after the other, but they are done together.
I thought to write a method with completion block, but or I'm doing something wrong, or there is another way to do this.

The animation is a uiview that move out of the screen (closeView) and the default animation of viewcontroller closing. 
I want the viewcontroller closes when is over the animation of view.

This is what i've done

```
- (void)closeViewWithCompletion:(void (^) (BOOL finish))handler {
    [self closeView];
    handler(YES);
}

-(void) closeView{
        [self.myview setFrame:CGRectMake(
                                          -self.myview.frame.size.width
                                          , self.myview.frame.origin.y
                                          , self.myview.frame.size.width
                                          , self.view.frame.size.height
                                          )];


        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
        [animation setDuration:.50];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        CALayer *layer = [self.myview layer];
        [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [greyMask setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0]];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [greyMask removeFromSuperview];
        }];
}
```

use:

```
[vc closeViewWithCompletion:^(BOOL finish) {
        [navController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
    }
];
```

Comment: show both of the animation code you need to execute one by one in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your `handler` block in `completionBlock` after your `closeView` Animation finishes.

```
- (void)closeViewWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL finish))handler {

    //closeView Animation 
     [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        //code for close view animation
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        handler(YES) //call your handler in completion block
    }];
 }

[vc closeViewWithCompletion:^(BOOL finish) {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
 }];
```